# I have 2 given names but I booked a flight ticket with just my first name

Tags: passports, tickets, bookings, filipino-citizens, china-airlines

So basically I have 2 names, “Ivy Maxine”. I put on my ticket “Ivy (Middle) Tejerero (Surname) Cuarteros”. Is there any problem with this? I don’t want to refund because they have a refund fee. I'm from the Philippines, going to Germany.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bought a ticket with Finnair, didn't enter my middle name](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/90093/bought-a-ticket-with-finnair-didnt-enter-my-middle-name)

Comment: I doubt it matters, but for completeness which airline(s)? I have 2 given names and 1 family (surname/last) name. When booking, including my 2nd given name has always been optional.

Comment: Generally it doesn't matter, but some airlines (particularly certain budget carriers) may have stricter rules: when booking you do sometimes see text saying something like "the name must match that on your passport exactly" and if you do there might be trouble.

Comment: My airline is China airline and i have heard that the refund system is so slow that’s why im so worried regarding this

Comment: Do you also have two family names? I would be more concerned about the family names going into the right spot, and making sure that matches what's on your travel documentation (passport, visa, etc.). See [One last name in Passport, Two last names in plane ticket](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/181231/47309)

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, airlines are more lenient with this at check-in than you would think they would be after reading their policies.  (I have a long three-word second given name that I avoid using whenever I can because it just confuses people.)

I think the worst case scenario is probably that they make you pay for the change at check-in, but more likely they don't.  There's no point in paying the change fee now to avoid the chance of having to pay it later.

Answer (score -3):

I think to avoid any unexpected inconvenience at the checkin/immigration counter, you must follow the way it is mentioned on your passport and ID card issued by your country.

Comment: This is not always true, as mentioned in the comments to the question and also does not really answer the question.