Incomplete first name and last name in flight ticket. Will there be any problem?
I booked an international flight ticket. My first name is AAA BBB. Surname is CCC DDD.
But I booked the flight ticket as BBB CCC. Will there be any problem?
Thank you.

Which airline(s)? Typically the name in your booking should match how it’s given in your passport. Why did you leave out AAA and DDD?

Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/188177/i-have-2-given-names-but-i-booked-a-flight-ticket-with-just-my-first-name

Its flydubai...

Boarded the flight no question asked regarding the name thank you all for replying

My name has a similar structure and many times I booked tickets using the name AAA DDD and never had problems being denied boarding or with border control agents.
Two inconveniences I can remember:

I couldn't use automated check in machines at the airport and I needed to go to the check in counter (no problems to check in with the agent).
I also couldn't accumulate miles on an account because my surname was DDD in the account and CCC DDD on the ticket.

Most likely this is not a problem, but going forward I suggest to use all the names if they fit the input fields. Besides mild inconveniences, there have been cases of people being denied boarding because their name is the same as a criminal and/or someone in the no-fly-list. The more names you have the less likely you are from being mistaken by someone else.

I’m not sure your example AAA/DDD is the same as that given by the OP (BBB/CCC). I couldn’t find FlyDubai’s passenger name policy (however this from another airline looks like a reliable common standard. IMHO the OP should check with the airline rather than risk finding out it’s not ok at the airport.
